# Is there an issue with the latest Kentico Delivery Client and Release build in Android

Tags: xamarin.android, kentico-kontent

I am having an issue with the latest DeliveryClient in Xamarin.Android.
The following  code snippet runs fine in a Debug build.

However, I get a runtime error by unchecking the two Packaging properties items, *Use Shared Runtime* and *Use Fast deployment* in the Android project properties. And you have to uncheck these when you are archiving an APK to be installed on a device.
Once I do that, I get the stack trace below, which isn’t very helpful, but it seems the http request is just going off somewhere and not being executed.

This makes me wonder if anyone has used this latest version of the *DeliveryClient* successfully in an Android Release build. This didn’t happen in earlier versions before the *DeliveryClientBuilder*.

```
    DeliveryClient client = DeliveryClientBuilder
                    .WithOptions(builder => builder
                        .WithProjectId("myProjectId")
                        .UseProductionApi
                        .WithMaxRetryAttempts(5)
                    .Build())
                    .Build();

     Task<string> content = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var res = client.GetItemAsync("hello").Result;
                    var helloFromKC = res.Item.GetString("message_from_kc");
                    return helloFromKC;
                });
```

> 04-18 18:24:16.408 I/mono-stdout(17908): One or more errors occurred.
>   One or more errors occurred.
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-8/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2164 04-18 18:24:16.578 I/mono-stdout(17908):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-8/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2164 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-8/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:562 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-8/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:532 
>     at App1.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass3_0+<b__1>d.MoveNext () [0x00014] in C:\TestApps\AndroidKenticoTest\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs:68 04-18 18:24:16.579 I/mono-stdout(17908):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-8/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:562

Comment: Could you identify the version of SDK that runs smoothly with this setup?

Comment: It seems to have been introduced with version 6. Versions 4 and 5 work with this setup. Also version 6 does not introduce the DeliveryClientBuilder so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Hi Dave, just FYI I'm finally able to reproduce the issue and going to investigate it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally debugged the source of this behavior. In Xamarin some reflection methods are [not available](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46198/where-is-system-reflection-assembly-getexecutingassembly) (or at least not fully supported) in Portable Class Library (PCL) and `GetExecutingAssembly()` is one of those methods.

As a result, Kentico Cloud Delivery's SDK private methods `GetSdkVersion()` and `GetSdkPackageId()` throw exception since they used this method.

As a quick workaround, you can reference SDK directly as a [project](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net) and comment out body of [GetSdkPackageId()](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/blob/91ed4a93a73fb2a5286fb2a53639dc549b135863/KenticoCloud.Delivery/Extensions/HttpRequestHeadersExtensions.cs#L43) and [GetSdkVersion()](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/blob/91ed4a93a73fb2a5286fb2a53639dc549b135863/KenticoCloud.Delivery/Extensions/HttpRequestHeadersExtensions.cs#L34) methods (just return some dummy string.) I'm going to create an issue and try to fix it in the SDK (and Nuget Package as well).

Update 1: In addition to (not fully) `GetExecutingAssembly()` support in Xamarin, it seems [it's not possible](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54678) to get valid path location for the assembly while using not a shared runtime (production mode).

Update 2: Created [issue](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/issues/160) on GitHub.

Update 3: The issue [is fixed](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/issues/160) in the SDK and the new patched [version 10.0.1](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/releases/tag/10.0.1) has been released. Let me know if it works for you.